# How to check if Tomcat clustering is working?

Tags: tomcat

I've set up two machines with Tomcat (using juju charms). I've followed this documentation to setup clustering: [cluster-howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/cluster-howto.html). My question is the following: What are some ways to test if the clustering is actually working?

I have deployed a [sample application](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/sample/) and it deployed on one machine but not on the second one. Are there any other ways to check if it's working?

**EDIT**: Application suggestions that I can test are very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a tomcat clustering walkthrough where it's demonstrated how to verify if the clustering is working. You can try to run the application **http://[ip-load-balancer]/examples/jsp/sessions/carts.html**. From there you add items into your cart and shutdown the machine that you had a session with. Then try to continue your session, if your cart is still full it means session replication is working.

Make sure you make `DummyCart.java` serializable and add `<distributable/>` to the `web.xml` file in the `/tomcat/webapps/examples/WEB-INF` directory.

The guide can be found here; http://krams915.blogspot.be/2011/10/tomcat-clustering-and-load-balancing_09.html

Answer (score 0):

There may  be now load balancer in front of these clusters.
One way is to print InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()  in your logs to check whether both clusters are getting called.

Comment: I'm not using a load balancer. The session replication is between all the nodes.

Answer (score -1):

Start a session, identify the Tomcat instance you're talking to, take it down, and see whether the session continues or whether you have to login again.